ERROR AL TRATAR DE INSERTAR DATOS. SQL
Me sale este error:
ERROR:  La llave (id_boleta)=(2019000000) no está presente en la tabla «estudiantes».inserción o actualización en la tabla «estudiante_materia» viola la llave foránea «fk_estudiantes_materia» 

ERROR:  inserción o actualización en la tabla «estudiante_materia» viola la llave foránea «fk_estudiantes_materia»
SQL state: 23503
Detail: La llave (id_boleta)=(2019000000) no está presente en la tabla «estudiantes».

Y este es mi código, es mi primer proyecto en PostgreSQL, y en sql en general.
CREATE TYPE genero AS ENUM ('Masculino','Femenino');

CREATE TABLE personas(
    id_persona SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    primerapellido VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    segundoapellido VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '---' ,
    genero genero,
    ciudad VARCHAR(30),
    delegacion_municipio VARCHAR(30),
    direccion VARCHAR(100),
    fecha_nacimiento DATE,
    telefono VARCHAR(50),
    correo VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE docente(
    id_profesor SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    id_persona SERIAL,
    grado_academico VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    area_especialidad VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '---',
    numero_docente VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT fk_persona_docentes FOREIGN KEY (id_persona) REFERENCES personas(id_persona)
);

CREATE TABLE estudiantes (
    id_estudiante SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    id_persona SERIAL,
    id_boleta BIGINT UNIQUE CHECK (id_boleta >= 2019000000),
    CONSTRAINT fk_persona_estudiantes FOREIGN KEY (id_persona) REFERENCES personas(id_persona)
);

CREATE TABLE Plantel (
    id_plantel SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    clave_plantel VARCHAR(50),
    nombre_plantel VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE carrera(
    id_carrera SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    id_plantel SERIAL,
    clave_carrera VARCHAR(50),
    nombre_carrera VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT fk_carrera_pantel FOREIGN KEY (id_plantel) REFERENCES Plantel(id_plantel)
);

CREATE TABLE materia(
    id_materia SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    id_carrera SERIAL,
    clave varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    nombre_materia varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    creditos float NOT NULL,
    semestre int,
    academia varchar(60),
    CONSTRAINT fk_materia_carrera FOREIGN KEY (id_carrera) REFERENCES carrera(id_carrera)
);

CREATE TABLE estudiante_materia(
    id_materia  SERIAL,
    id_boleta BIGINT,
    calificacion DOUBLE PRECISION,
    CONSTRAINT fk_materia_estudiantes FOREIGN KEY (id_materia) REFERENCES materia(id_materia),
    CONSTRAINT fk_estudiantes_materia FOREIGN KEY (id_boleta) REFERENCES estudiantes(id_boleta)
);

CREATE TABLE aula(
    id_aula SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_aula VARCHAR(4),
    tipo VARCHAR(20),
    capacidad INT
);


CREATE TABLE horarios(
    id_horario SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    id_materia SERIAL,
    id_aula SERIAL,
    dia VARCHAR(20),
    hora_inicio TIME,
    hora_fin TIME,
    CONSTRAINT fk_horario_materia FOREIGN KEY (id_materia) REFERENCES materia(id_materia),
    CONSTRAINT fk_horario_aula FOREIGN KEY (id_aula) REFERENCES aula(id_aula)
);

CREATE TABLE grupos(
    id_grupo SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    id_profesor SERIAL,
    id_materia SERIAL,
    grupo varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    numero_estudiantes INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_grupos_profesor FOREIGN KEY (id_profesor) REFERENCES docente(id_profesor),
    CONSTRAINT fk_grupos_materia FOREIGN KEY (id_materia) REFERENCES materia(id_materia)
);



gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme.Ese es mi codigo para insertar datos. (complemento del codigo de pregunta)
select * from estudiantes where id_persona >0;
select * from horarios;
select * from estudiante_materia;
select id_materia,id_carrera,creditos, nombre_materia, semestre from materia;
select id_carrera, count(*) from materia group by id_carrera order by 
id_carrera;
insert into estudiante_materia(id_boleta,id_materia,calificacion) values
(2019000000,1,8.2),
(2019000000,2,6.1),
(2019000000,3,6.2),
(2019000000,4,9.2),
(2019000000,5,2.1),
(2019000001,6,10),
(2019000001,7,1.1),
(2019000002,8,8.6),
(2019000003,9,3.4),
(2019000003,10,8),
(2019000003,11,8.5),
(2019000003,12,8.7),
(2019000003,13,2.9),
(2019000003,14,10)


Para poder insertar en esa tabla(estudiante_materia)  debes tener insertado los códigos correspondiente en las tablas estudiantes y materia, pues tienes FKs que apuntan a ellas:
 CONSTRAINT fk_materia_estudiantes FOREIGN KEY (id_materia) REFERENCES materia(id_materia),
 CONSTRAINT fk_estudiantes_materia FOREIGN KEY (id_boleta) REFERENCES estudiantes(id_boleta)
);

